# How do I hide the submit button for a file field in ruby on rails, unless the file field is set? Using carrierwave direct gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am currently using carrierwave direct to upload files directly to Amazon S3. However, if one presses the submit button without submitting a file it gives an XML error, "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." I would like to be able to prevent users from pressing the file submit button, unless a file has been selected. If there is another type of solution to handle this error then let me know...

Comment: The standard html file upload includes the button automatically. If you disable this button then the user can not select the file(s) to be uploaded. You can check via JavaScript if a file has been selected and/or server-side script should also check for one or more files before processing the request. This link to MDN shows so examples of using JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified which button I was talking about. I was asking how to hide the submit button for the form until a user selects a file. However, it looks like the link you provided was exactly what I was looking for.